# Can't get MongoDB to start?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

Version 2.67 of MongoDB is installed.  When I run MongoD in Terminal (mac os x 10.95), here is the message I get. (BTW, I have tried Sudo)![Error][1]

```
Alis-MacBook-Air:~ alitaghikhani$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2015-02-08T19:00:43.915-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=40591 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Alis-MacBook-Air.local
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] 
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-02-08T19:00:43.916-0500 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.919-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-02-08T19:00:43.920-0500 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-02-08T19:00:43.920-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the first time you are running `MongoDB`, make sure you have you have owner permission to create `mongod.lock` file to create in `/data/db` path.

```
sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db
```

Comment: and also, try deleting mongod.lock or killing any mongod process from Activity Monitor

Comment: force quitting in activity monitor worked for me.  I wonder where this process is running if terminal has been quit?

Answer (score 0):

first try:

```
mongo localhost
```

to see if there already a mongod instance running. if not, you should delete the `mongod.lock`

```
sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

if means you had an unclear shutdown of mongod.

Important: this assumes you don't have anything important in the DB because it seems it's running on your macbook air.